# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' error

Tags: php

[picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kzFW.png)I have this code:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET["update"])){
        $id = $_GET["id"] ?? null;

        $where = array("id"=>$id);
        $row = $obj->select_record("medicines",$where);

        ?>
```

I get this :

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in C:\wamp\www\New folder\index.php on line 42

Is there any alternative to the above code?

Comment: What PHP version are you using? I'd guess < 7, http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

Comment: Looks like you've written some PHP7 code and you're not using PHP7..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
 $id = $_GET['id']?$_GET['id']:null;
```